# Remotely initiate windows updates

Tags: windows-7, scripting, windows-update

I have a network with countless workstations on it and the windows updates are done through WSUS in push cycles to allow us to use a generic image and configuration and avoid network congestion.

I have a number of workstations in storage that are connected once a month for a few days to recieve updates, however not all of them fall within their push cycle.

I want to avoid going to each machine and clicking "check updates" as that would require me to connect a monitor, mouse and keyboard.

Is there a way (preferably through powershell but im open minded) to initiate a check and install of updates on a remote system?  Lets say for 1 system at a time right now, I can add a file reader and a look later.

NOTE: the configuration of the WSUS server is above my pay grade, im simply being asked to ensure these machines are updated.

Thanks for any help or hints

Comment: something like [teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) will let you access the servers from your own seat - no need for an outside mouse/keyboard/screen

Comment: Windows supports remote desktop out of the box I believe.

Comment: What do you mean by "push cycles?" WSUS/Windows Update is a "pull" technology, not a "push" technology.

Comment: Seems I know nothing of WSUS, MDMarra I am not sure WHY but bottom line is these workstations have to be online for around a week to pull updates, even those whos status says "never checked" in Windows Update.  Also I COULD remote desktop, but with the numbers I would really prefer a scripted solution. RDP is how we are doing it now but even that is time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

`wuauclt /detectnow` is the command that you want. It will force the workstation to detect new updates. If they're configured to automatically install updates from GPO, then it will also download and install them as well.

This command can be wrapped in an `invoke-command` block and run remotely via PowerShell.

Comment: Do you know of anyway to perform this without invoke? I get a failure to connect because the service is not running on the remote computer and I am not sure how to get around it, is there a way to perhaps start that service then stop it remotely?

Answer (score 0):

Try psexec

```
Psexec \\servername "wuauclt /detectnow"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the most versatile and workable way was to use [WUInstall](https://wuinstall.com/).

I'm a happy user.